# How to get values from drag and drop container in Angular 8

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular8

I'm trying to get values from angular8 drag and drop but the problem is that I apparently can only get values subsequently to a drag and drop event. The problem is that I didn't find a way to distinguish which is the current container .

I've tried to distinguish containers by their ID this way:

```js
let events: Array<string>;
if (event.container.id = 'cdk-drop-list-0') {
  events = event.container.connectedTo[0].data;
} else {
  events = event.container.data;
}
```

However, it doesn't work because it seems to something like a dynamic ID...

Here's my code (taking from the official Angular documentation and shapped to my needs):

- HTML part:

```html
    <div class="dragdrop-container">
        <h2><mat-icon>delete_sweep</mat-icon></h2>
        <div
            cdkDropList
            #addableFieldsList="cdkDropList"
            [cdkDropListData]="addableFields"
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[displayedFieldsList]"
            class="dragdrop-list"
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <div class="dragdrop-box" *ngFor="let item of addableFields" cdkDrag>{{"workstation." + item | translate}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dragdrop-container">
        <h2><mat-icon>playlist_add</mat-icon></h2>
        <div
            cdkDropList
            #displayedFieldsList="cdkDropList"
            [cdkDropListData]="displayedFields"
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[addableFieldsList]"
            class="dragdrop-list"
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <div class="dragdrop-box" *ngFor="let item of displayedFields" cdkDrag>{{"workstation." + item | translate}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

- Typescript code:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-drag-and-drop-fields',
      templateUrl: './drag-and-drop-fields.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./drag-and-drop-fields.component.scss']
    })
    export class DragAndDropFieldsComponent {

      constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
        this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
      }

      displayedFields = [
        'event_name',
        'event_date',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
        'duration',
        'summary',
      ];

      addableFields = [
        'location',
        'iCalUID',
        'status',
        'created_at',
        'html_link',
      ];

      drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
        if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
          moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
        } else {
          transferArrayItem(
            event.previousContainer.data,
            event.container.data,
            event.previousIndex,
            event.currentIndex);
        }
      }
    }
```

What I want is symply get values from the "dragdrop-container" and push them into my form (I know how to do this part ;) )

If someone could help me, it would be awesome!!

Thanks by advance.

EDIT: Answer in comment reply ;)

Comment: I've finally figured out what to do:

I simply added an argument to the "drop" function, thus I can know from which container the event come from!

I hope this will help someone one day :)

Answer (score 2):

Easy solution is to **assign id property** with each connected list.

### Like in your code

```
<div class="dragdrop-container">
     <h2><mat-icon>playlist_add</mat-icon></h2>
        <div
            cdkDropList
            id="playlist_add"
            #displayedFieldsList="cdkDropList"
            [cdkDropListData]="displayedFields"
            [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[addableFieldsList]"
            class="dragdrop-list"
            (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
            <div class="dragdrop-box" *ngFor="let item of displayedFields" cdkDrag> 
                {{"workstation." + item | translate}}
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### and in your typescript code you can do something like this:

```
     drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
            if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
              moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
            } else {

            if(event.container.id === 'playlist_add') {
              // Do Something
            }
              transferArrayItem(
                event.previousContainer.data,
                event.container.data,
                event.previousIndex,
                event.currentIndex);
           }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: this is the right way of doing it and should be accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

this works for me. Add this to the container

```
 (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event, customfield);"
```

and in the onDrop, you can get the dragged item. The customfield help to identity which container its dragged to.

```
 var moveditem= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.container.data[event.currentIndex])));
```

Comment: This is what i finally did (see my self reply) ^^